# Wanting to convert webmail logins into a SQL file

Tags: php, html, sql, webmail

I have a site in which users have webmail accounts. I'm using AfterLogic Webmail, if that is important info. I want to take all of the webmail logins(email and passwords) and convert them into a SQL Table. Another option would be to login with webmail without going to see emails, however I would need to be able to select admin and non admin accounts for this.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to note here is, Afterlogic WebMail users don't have passwords. Initially, each user has one email account associated with that user ID, and password for that account is probably what you're looking for. It's possible to add multiple email accounts under the same user account (in the Pro version) but we'll omit that part for simplicity reasons.

We thought it would be a good idea to provide a sample that demonstrates exporting user data from our webmail database, you can find the sample at:

https://afterlogic.com/docs/webmail-pro-8/developers-guide/exporting-list-of-user-accounts-with-passwords

It creates .SQL file and stores user ID, email and password for each user.

Note that this is only about email users. In WebMail, there's only one admin account and its credentials are stored in the configuration file, not the database.